# Establishing a multi-hop ssh tunnel through an ssh1 server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I'm having trouble tunneling through an ssh1 server. This is on a customer's machine and no, they won't update to ssh2.

---

A bit of background: I can successfully tunnel through the customer's gateway

```
localhost -> gateway.customer.example.com -> srv.customer.internal
```

using this configuration

```
Host gateway
    Hostname gateway.customer.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    ...

Host srv-tunnel
    ProxyCommand ssh gateway -W srv.customer.internal:22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    ...
```

and then simply

```
$ ssh srv-tunnel
```

which works great and establishes the tunnel automatically, using the keyfile `~/.ssh/mykey`.

---

I tried to use a similar config for this multi-hop tunnel:

```
localhost -> gateway.customer.example.com
                |
                v
             onemoregateway.customer.internal -> srv2.customer.internal
```

but this time the **`onemoregateway` is running ssh 1 and does not have `nc` available**. I can ssh to `onemoregateway` and the prompt tells me `The only permitted commands are ssh and scp.` When I try to set up a forwarding connection as above, ssh exits with error `stdio forwarding require Protocol 2`.

However, I can't ssh directly from `onemoregateway` to `srv2`, because the private key is only on my local machine. To make things even more complicated, I need one key for `gateway`, and another key for `onemoregateway` and `srv2`.

So, how can I tunnel through to `srv2`?

<sub>I feel that it must be possible somehow, since my colleagues did it using Putty+Pageant in Windows, but I'm on linux</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to do it, but <strike>it seems there is no way to make the tunneling transparent.</strike>

```
Host gateway
    Hostname gateway.customer.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    ...

Host tunnel-to-srv2
    ProxyCommand ssh gateway -W onemoregateway.customer.internal
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myotherkey
    Protocol 1
    LocalForward 10022 srv2.customer.internal:22
    ...

Host srv2
    Hostname localhost
    Port 10022
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myotherkey
    Protocol 1
    ...
```

And now I have to do

```
$ ssh tunnel-to-srv2
```

and, finally, in a separate terminal*

```
$ ssh srv2
```

*<sub>I cant't find a way to send the tunneling ssh process to the background, not even with `-fNT`</sub>

---

Edit: turns out, the `onemoregateway` does indeed have `nc` and I can run it, but I need to use the full path `/bin/nc`

So, after all I have this configuration

```
Host gateway
    Hostname gateway.customer.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    ...

Host tunnel-to-srv2
    ProxyCommand ssh gateway -W onemoregateway.customer.internal
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myotherkey
    Protocol 1
    ...

Host srv2
    ProxyCommand ssh tunnel-to-srv2 /bin/nc srv2.customer.internal 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myotherkey
    Protocol 1
    ...
```

and I get transparent tunnel hopping by just running

```
$ ssh srv2
```